# Best / Recommended way to identify the inactive sites in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, auditing, reporting, last-modified-date

I am looking for an accurate solution that can identify the inactive sites of the SharePoint Online tenant.

I already checked the different blogs available which suggest using the **LastContentModifiedDate** or **LastItemUserModifiedDate**  properties but those are not accurate. It does not match with the real scenario I did testing with.

Is there any other way/property available which provides accurate results?

I am open to all kinds of possible solutions i.e., CSOM, PowerShell, Graph API

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to add a comment, but this might be worth a try: from PnP.Powershell you can extract information from the audit property of the document (if this isn't correct $site_info below will show you all the information you can get from a site):

```
$url = "Your site name here"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $url -Interactive
$site_info = Get-PnPSite
$last_modified = $site_info.audit.context.web.LastItemModifiedDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Get Inactive SharePoint Online Sites using  PowerShell

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
 
#Variables 
$AdminSiteURL ="https://crescent-admin.sharepoint.com"
$CSVFile = "C:\Temp\SiteData.csv"
 
#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred= Get-Credential
 
#Connect to Admin Center
Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminSiteURL -Credential $Cred
 
#Get All Site Collections
$Sites = Get-SPOSite -Limit All 
$SiteData = @()
 
#Loop through each site collection
ForEach($Site in $Sites)
{
    Write-host -f Yellow "Getting Data for Site:" $Site.URL
    Try { 
        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Site.URL)
        $Ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)
          
        #Get the Root Web
        $Web = $Ctx.web
        $Ctx.Load($Web)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
  
        #Get the last modified date of the site
        $SiteData += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            SiteTitle = $Web.Title
            URL = $Web.Url
            LastModified= $Web.LastItemUserModifiedDate
        }
    }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error:" $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
#Export the results to CSV
$SiteData | Export-CSV $CSVFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Reference https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/08/sharepoint-online-find-unused-sites-using-powershell.html

Answer (score 0):

Agree it is confusing. I did research on properties below:

- LastContentModifiedDate Site property
- LastItemModifiedDate Web property
- LastItemUserModifiedDate Web property
- LastModifiedDateTime MS Graph site property

In terms of what event triggers which property, and [Here are the results](https://vladilen.com/sharepoint/spo-site-lastcontentmodifieddate-vs-lastitemmodifieddate-vs-lastitemusermodifieddate/)